# Python Setter method in class not giving expected output

Tags: python, class, methods, constructor, getter-setter

I'm trying to update the rank field in the node using setters in Python. Below is the code I've used:

```
class Tree(object):
    def __init__(self,u):
        self.parent=u
        self.rank=0

    def get_parent(self):
        return self.parent

    def get_rank(self):
        return self.rank

    def set_parent(self,v):
        self.parent=v

    def set_rank(self,v):
        self.rank=v
```

And then I'm running the following code:

```
Tree(0).get_rank()
Tree(0).set_rank(5)
Tree(0).get_rank()
```

Output:

```
0
```

Expected Output:

```
5
```

Here, the output I'm getting is 0 itself instead of 5 which I'm expecting. Can anybody let me know where exactly am I going wrong in the code or even conceptually?

Comment: `Tree(0)` on 2nd line is not same reference as `Tree(0)` on 1st line. Try doing `id(Tree(0))` for both lines to see it.

Comment: You are performing your operations on a new object each time, so you're throwing away your intermediate state. Besides, getters and setters are very common in Java, but are very uncommon in Python. Just set and read the attributes directly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create an object of your class:

```
tree = Tree(0)
tree.get_rank()
tree.set_rank(5)
tree.get_rank()
```

```
5
```

Answer (score 2):

You are creating and using a new `Tree` object on each line:

```
Tree(0).get_rank()   # first tree object
Tree(0).set_rank(5)  # second tree object
Tree(0).get_rank()   # third tree object
```

So, when you call `get_rank` on the third one, it's freshly initialized, so its rank is 0.